# Function required from https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable

Tags: javascript

I am using https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable and i need to write an if/else function that can basically tell if you have dragged the right tile to the right target and if you haven't, bounce it back to where it came from (same order).

Pretty sure i use this event:
Element is dropped into the list from another list

```
 onAdd: function (/**Event*/evt) {
    var itemEl = evt.item;  // dragged HTMLElement
    evt.from;  // previous list
    // + indexes from onEnd
    },
```

First off, is evt a common parameter? (I am not a coder).

Please find my working code here:
https://codepen.io/maevemacn/pen/XMvZjP
this does not include the external sortable.min.js file

Any help greatly appreciated
Maeve

Comment: evt is the event object, which is handed to the function when an event is fired: http://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#event-object

Comment: Where/how do you define what is an allowed target? Do you have a set of mappings that indicates where something is allowed to go? I mean something like the following; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyYyZJ

Comment: @plenderj : Yes have updated that here: http://codepen.io/maevemacn/pen/qmEdBp

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this then? This is a minimal implementation of what I believe you're after.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdGoNe

```
            onMove: function (evt, originalEvent) {
                var textOfItemBeingDragged = evt.dragged.innerText.toLowerCase();
                var destinationIndexOfTarget = evt.related.getAttribute('destination-index');
                var areWeAllowedToDragToHere = allowedMappings[textOfItemBeingDragged] ==
                    destinationIndexOfTarget;
                return areWeAllowedToDragToHere;
            }
```

onMove does the interesting work - we check whether we're allowed to drop this item into the specific box